# How to validate the credential filed with secret key for sign in with google in .net core?

Tags: .net-core, jwt, google-signin

I am creating the web application with google sign in. But I am not using the.net identity for that. I use the simple google client library with adding the JS and related div in view.

Here I get the credential parameter in the action after the sign-in with google. Also, when I decode that credential(jwt token) get the value. But my question is that how I can validate that token with the secret key?

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration where you add JWT Token authentication, you need to set up `Authority` to the address of Google's OpenIdConnect server. Then Authentication middleware will handle requesting public keys from Google and validating the token signature.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = "https://<google-oidc-address>";
    });
...

app.UseAuthentication();
```

It's actually not a google specific thing, you can point `Authority` to any OpenIdConnect provider to validate tokens from it and populate the principal with claims from the token.

Answer (score 0):

For that, we can authenticate the token by google API. I created the demo for that project on git https://github.com/hardik-sanghavi/NetCoreSignInWithGoogle